# Prestashop: Override URL scheme of Blog module

Tags: url, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I bought a Blog module in order to write blog posts directly in Prestashop : https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/blog-forum-actualites/25908-blog.html

But I found out that this module forces me to have 3 components in my blog posts URLs like this: `blog/post/post-title`

In the module settings I can choose other words for the first two components (e.g. `content/article/post-title`) but I can't delete one of the components.

I'd like to get rid of one of the components in order to get this scheme: `blog/post-title`

How can I do this without breaking too much the code of the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is done correctly in the module, you need to edit

```
public function hookModuleRoutes()
{
}
```

in the main module file. Edit that router which responsible for the post. It should be something like this:

```
return array(
    'module-YOURMODULENAME-CONTROLLERNAME' => array(
        'controller' => 'CONTROLLERNAME',
        'rule'       => 'blog/post/{title}',
        'keywords'   => array(
            'title'        => array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*')
        ),
        'params'     => array(
            'fc'     => 'module',
            'module' => 'YOURMODULENAME',
        )
    )
);
```

so you can edit

```
'rule'       => 'blog/post/{title}'
```

to

```
'rule'       => 'blog/{title}'
```

but be careful and check if no other blog page has the same rule.

Comment: Great, I managed to get rid of the "post" part.
Now I'd like to remove the `id` of the post in the URL. But is seems that if I delete the `id` in the `rule` the argument is not passed in the $_GET and my controller doesn't use the good template. How can I pass the argument without having it in the URL?

Comment: In this case, you need to have unique titles for each post and pass it within a URL. And then in your controller, you need to get your post by title or get post id by title and then load a post

Comment: I used the `url_alias` to identify my blog post. Thanks!